# Modem emulator for Ubuntu

Tags: linux, ubuntu, modem

Anyone know of an end-to-end modem emulator which supports AT commands?

I've tried several Windows products but none seem to work with Cygwin. Something native to Linux and Unix is preferable.

And since this is for testing code that needs to interact with many local modems the emulated devices need to be available as local TTY devices.

Qtopia's Phonesim and Atinterface are unavailable as they took the code down.

Dosbox looked promising but the local interface is only available within the emulated DOS environment.

Thanks for help

Answer (score 1):

You may use dosbox nevertheless together with a litte application tunneling a network socket? on the windows side, you may use [vspe](http://www.lmgtfy.com/?q=vspe&l=1) to connect to the device.

Answer (score 0):

The same post in Ubuntu forums in June 2008, word for word. 
http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=831840

Have you tried the T38 project in Ubuntu?